# How I can set quality resolution on YouTube video with react-native-youtube-iframe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, youtube

I'm able to do everything that I need with react-native-youtube-iframe. The only thing that it's missing is the ability to set resolution. I would like to set the resolution to full hd, but from the documentation there is only onPlaybackQualityChange, that is a "callback" when the resolution change automatically. I would like at the beginning have a resolution of 1080, if the internet connection is not appropriate I'm fine if YouTube put lower. The problem that at the moment start with 480 that is really low.

https://lonelycpp.github.io/react-native-youtube-iframe/component-props

thank you in advance.

Comment: Provide the code you're using. The link refers to the documentation of that specific functionality, but not **your** current code.

Comment: How can I double tap to fast forward and rewind like the youtube app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible anymore :/

> The getPlaybackQuality, setPlaybackQuality, and
> getAvailableQualityLevels functions are no longer supported

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#october-24,-2019